# Convert grib file to netcdf (jpeg format)

Tags: netcdf, grib

I've download weather forecast files from the ARPEGE that arrived in a file format like this "GRIBHS020+0000:00.jpeg". According to the person who managed the data, it is still a grib file that has been altered with this function "grib_set -r -s 'packingType=grid_jpeg' $f ${f}.jpeg. I need to convert this file to netcdf, but the data manager does not know how to do this. I've tried nearly everything (cdo: cdo -f nc copy, Eccodes: grib_to_netcdf, NCL ncl_convert2nc), but nothing works. For instance, this is the grib_to_netcdf output.

grib_to_netcdf -o test.nc grid.arpege-forecast.hs020+0024:00.grib
grib_to_netcdf: Version 2.12.3
grib_to_netcdf: Processing input file 'grid.arpege-forecast.hs020+0024:00.grib'.
grib_to_netcdf: Found 1018 GRIB fields in 1 file.
grib_to_netcdf: Ignoring key(s): method, type, stream, refdate, hdate
grib_to_netcdf: Creating netCDF file 'test.nc'
grib_to_netcdf: NetCDF library version: 4.6.2 of Dec 17 2018 19:36:03 $
grib_to_netcdf: Creating large (64 bit) file format.
ECCODES ERROR   :  Cannot handle fields for different levtypes.

ECCODES ERROR   :  Please split input data into different files. Exiting!

Any suggestions are highly welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert using netcdf-java:

```
java -cp toolsUI-5.4.2.jar ucar.nc2.write.Nccopy -i GRIBHS020+0114_00.jpeg -o GRIBHS020+0114_00.nc -st standard -sh -f netcdf4_classic
```

The netcdf-java can be downloaded from:
https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/downloads/netcdf-java/

and you will need to setup the netcdf-c library to write as netCDF4 using the nccopy featur:
https://docs.unidata.ucar.edu/netcdf-java/current/userguide/cdm_utility_programs.html#nccopy